# What is the difference between these two methods for importing a javascript module?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm new to javascript development.  I'm using npm.

I wanted to generate some uuids so I found a uuid package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

I installed it by running
`npm install uuid`

Now, I want to use this package in my code.

I found that there are 2 ways to do it.  The npm docs suggest:

```
// Generate a v4 UUID (random) 
const uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');
uuidV4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

But I guessed I could also do (which seems to work):

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
console.info(uuid.v4());
```

My questions:

- What are the differences between these?
- How can I tell what a module exports so I know what I can import and under what path?  For example, it seems I also could have done `import v4 from 'uuid'`... but I don't really understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

require is the es5 way to include a module in your project.

import is the es6 way to include a module in your project.

If you need to support older browsers and wish to use es6 features, you will need to use a transpilier such as Babel to convert your code into es5 format.

With import you can take pieces of the module. Lets use this as an example:

```
// test.js
export default () => { console.log("Hi, I'm a default export"); }

export NotDefault = () => { console.log("I am not the default export"); }
```

Now if you were to try to:

```
import NotDefault from "test.js";
```

You wouldn't actually be importing NotDefault, you would import the default export.

To import NotDefault, you would use the following format:

```
import { NotDefault } from "test.js";
```

**ES5 Syntax**

```
module.exports = function() {
    // this is now the default export of this file.
    // you can use this file in another by typing var MyVar = require("module_name");
}

exports.MyFunc = function() {
    // this is also exported from this file
    // you can use this by var MyVar = require("module_name").myFunc;
}
```

**ES6 Syntax**

```
default export function() {
    // this is the default export of this file
    // use can use me by typing import MyVar from "module_name";
}

export const MyFunc = function() {
    // this is also exported and can be used by typing
    // import { MyFunc } from "module_name";
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: es6 is supported by all major browsers(Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10, Edge) besides IE

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry I was thinking about supporting older browsers, let me amend my statement.

Comment: Thanks.  Why am i able to import from "uuid" and do not have to specify "uuid.js"?  What exactly is the identifier in the string?  How is the import found?  Is there a search path or something?

Comment: Please don't mix up normal functions and arrow functions, this is not what your answer is about. Keep them as function declarations.

Comment: Thank you Bergi. Your comment caused me to do some research and learn something.